# AMPL implement constraint

Tags: optimization, ampl

I'm trying to implement the following in AMPL:

$$ i \in [N], j \in[N] \backslash \{i\}, t \in [T] $$

I have so far written the following:

```
subject to Con{i in PP,t in TT, j in PP : j != i}:
```

but it does not feel correct, is it?
I also have a question about implementing this:
$$ i \neq j,t $$
in a constraint, i'm only getting one to work:

```
subject to {i in PP,t in TT, j in PP : j != i}:
```

Comment: Load your `model` and `data` such that they don't use the solve command. Then do a `display`on the set operations that you want to validate. example you could try `display {i in PP,t in TT, j in PP : j != i};` to check if you are getting the correct selection from the sets.

Comment: @prash Column 1 newer equals column 3, which is correct. Tried to copy the result in here, but it got messy ;)

Comment: Your first constraint syntax looks correct to me. Are you getting an error, or you're just second-guessing yourself? For your second question, I am not sure what you are asking. Your constraint looks the same as the first one (except that you are missing a constraint name)

Answer (score 2):

This looks most like the math (and avoids checking for every $(i,j,t)$ a logical condition that depends only on $i$ and $j$):

```
{i in PP, j in PP diff {i}, t in TT}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntax:

```
subject to cons {i in PP,t in TT, j in PP : j diff i}:
```

Or

```
subject to cons {i in PP,t in TT, j in PP : j<>i}:
```